# What happens when I try to run firefox on a remote server from my local machine

Tags: server, firefox, ssh, remote-desktop

I am connecting to a remote server through putty. `whereis firefox` shows that Firefox is installed on the remote machine.

Now, I want to know what is going to happen when I run `firefox`.

Normally, if I were working on my local linux machine, and if I did firefox there, then it would open the interface locally and open the window.

Now, if I am doing the same on a remote machine through putty, wouldnt it open the firefox window on the remote machine. Who tells the remote server `dont open firefox window here, but send it to the user's machine who has logged in?`

Also, what info does the server send to user,as part of firefox's visual interface. Do I need to install something on my local machine, to be able to receive that info? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ssh option X11 forwarding enabled, `firefox` will open it's window on you local X display. (This is not something one would usually do, but it's quite possible.)

The environment variable `DISPLAY` tells firefox where to show it's window.

`ssh` takes care of setting DISPLAY in this case. Try

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

You do not need anything special locally, except the normal X server that you are running normally under Ubuntu.